# Is it possible to make grequests and requests_cache work together?

Tags: python, caching, request, python-requests, gevent

Look at this code:

```
import requests
import grequests
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache('bla')

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://python-tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
results = grequests.map(rs)
```

I would expect that after executing this I will find `bla.sqlite` file in the current directory and executing

```
results = grequests.map(rs)
```

will be MUCH faster because data will be taken from sqlite cache. Unfortunately this is not true, file wasn't created at all and there is no speedup. When I use requests insetead of grequests everything works fine. So the question is a title says: **Is it possible to make grequests and requests_cache work together?** and if yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `requests_cache.install_cache()` function patches `requests.Session`, but you already imported `grequests`, which used:

```
from requests import Session
```

As such, `grequests` never uses the patched session object.

Move the import to *after* you installed the cache:

```
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache('bla')
import grequests
```

Alternatively, create a [`CachedSession` object](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#requests_cache.core.CachedSession) and pass that in to the `grequests.get()` (and related) methods as the `session` parameter:

```
import grequests
import requests_cache

session = requests_cache.CachedSession('bla')

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://python-tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = (grequests.get(u, session=session) for u in urls)
results = grequests.map(rs)
```

Take into account that the cache storage backend may not be able to handle the corcurrent access safely. The `sqlite` backend uses a thread lock, for example, which might well clash.

Comment: OK, now timing. Fetching 1k URLs using grequests without caching takes 43s. With caching enabled, it takes 180s  for the first time and 25s every next time. Hard trade-off...

Comment: @mnowotka: Right, the backend storage may be affected by the concurrent access; the `sqlite` uses a thread lock, for example.

Comment: Which one would you suggest to use in that case?

Comment: You could experiment with the [`fast_safe` option](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#requests-cache-backends-sqlite), which sets [`PRAGMA synchronous = 0`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous); this won't eliminate the thread lock however. The `memory` backend does no locking, use that as a baseline, then also compare the redis and mongo backends. I adapted the module for using Memcached (on Google App Engine) with ease, that could be an option too.

Comment: but since I only ever used the memcached backend, I cannot make any more specific recommendations.

Comment: OK, that's enough information, now I know what to do. Very helpful answer, thank you very much.

Comment: I would be soooo grateful if you could check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117176/too-many-urls-in-greqests-map-causes-gevent-hub-loopexit-only-on-mac

Comment: @mnowotka: I saw it already; sorry, no answer from me on that one.