# How do I get multiple resources asynchrously with Flask?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, python-requests, gevent

I have a flask app that runs via uwsgi on nginx. When a user makes a request I need to make multiple API calls to different services. I'd like to do the calls at the same time in order to speed things up for the users (none of the calls are dependent on each other). I'd like to also cache these responses to save even further.  I am trying to do this w/ gevent but running into troubles trying to pass the request context to the child processes. I get the following error: "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cache import Cache
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app=app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem',
            'CACHE_DIR': '/path/to/cache',})


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    def get_external(i, request):
        with app.app_context():
            with app.test_request_context():
                if i == 'first':
                    return first_request()
                elif i == 'second':
                    return second_request()

    threads = [gevent.spawn(get_external, i, request) for i in ['first', 'second']]
    gevent.joinall(threads)
    first = threads[0].get(block=False)
    second = threads[1].get(block=False)
    return render_template('index.html', first=first, second=second)


@cache.cached(timeout=10)
def first_request():
    r = requests.get('http://api.example1.com?' + request.args.get('query'))
    my_list = []
    for row in r.json():
        d = {}
        d['article_id'] = row['article_id']
        my_list.append(d)
    return my_list


@cache.cached(timeout=10000)
def second_request():
    r = requests.get('http://api.example2.com?' + request.args.get('query'))
    my_list = []
    for row in r.json():
        d = {}
        d['id'] = row['user_id']
        my_list.append(d)
    return my_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Also, if gevent is the wrong tool for this job then **PLEASE** let me know. I am certainly not an expert in python and have never used gevent before but it does seem like there s/b an easier way to do this, no?

EDIT: I've tried the grequests module with requests-cache but [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406830/is-it-possible-to-make-grequests-and-requests-cache-work-together) it isn't very good because of it's use of sqlite as the backend (I also need to use files for the backend instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does gevent's joinall() block until all the threads have returned? If not, then i feel like somethng is missing here. If you start a couple threads asynchronously then you need to periodically check to see if the threads have all returned and, when they have, call render_template given the return vals. I may be missing something here as I haven't used gevent.

Also, The way you're building threads feels strange to me... It might not be a good idea to use a list comprehension given that for each i you have to explicitly check for it in get_external(), which seems messy. Instead it might be more clear defining specific functions for each thread and appending each new thread to threads one at a time. You can then later refer to them explicitly.

Caching responsed would be pretty easy to do. For each function, track the last returned value and when that value was returned. If cuurent time - prev check time is greater than some threshold then check again and update cached value and check time, else return cached value. If you want something more robust, you should look into redis or memcache.

Comment: thanks. Caching is already done via the @cache decorator. If there's a better way than via gevent then I'm all ears!